# Why will data.frame not convert column type 'unknown' to date?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Friends of stack**overflow**,
I am having a heck of a time getting my fake data.frame to convert to class type 'date'.

#### Data

```
library(anytime)

fake.data<-data.frame(
  
  date = c('01/01/2019', '01/02/2019', '01/03/2019', '01/04/2019', '01/05/2019', '01/06/2019', '01/07/2019',
           '01/01/2019', '01/02/2019', '01/03/2019', '01/04/2019', '01/05/2019', '01/06/2019', '01/07/2019'),
  
  location = c('Point A', 'Point A', 'Point A', 'Point A', 'Point A', 'Point A', 'Point A',
               'Point B', 'Point B', 'Point B', 'Point B', 'Point B', 'Point B', 'Point B'
  ),
  
  vehicle = c('ZZ12', 'ZZ12', 'AA12', 'AA12', 'AA12', 'AA12', 'ZZ12',
              'ZZ12', 'ZZ12', 'AA12', 'AA12', 'AA12', 'AA12', 'ZZ12'),
  
  count = c(2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2,
            3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 6, 6),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

> The structure returns:

```
>str(fake.data$date)
 chr [1:14] "01/01/2019" "01/02/2019" "01/03/2019" "01/04/2019" "01/05/2019" "01/06/2019" "01/07/2019" "01/01/2019" "01/02/2019" ...
```

My attempts to change the class type to 'Date' continue to fail. For example:

```
fake.data$date<- anydate(fake.data$date)
```

Returns:

```
> head(str(fake.data))
'data.frame':   14 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ date    : Date, format: "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04" ...
 $ location: chr  "Point A" "Point A" "Point A" "Point A" ...
 $ vehicle : chr  "ZZ12" "ZZ12" "AA12" "AA12" ...
 $ count   : num  2 1 4 4 3 4 2 3 3 1 ...
```

This seems great, but when I try to utilize this for visualization (ie plots), I get what I think are as.POSIXct:

[image: Screenshot of interactive hover plot]

> The date no longer renders in the format..just changes in to this odd numeric. Any ideas?

I have also tried `as.Date`, `as.character(as.Date(...))`, to no avail. Oddly..the date on the bottom of the chart still renders the correct format.

#### Copy of the app

```
ui<- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    plotOutput("plotthis", hover="clickthis"),    
    tableOutput("rawdata")                      
  )
)
server<- shinyServer(function(input,output) {

  output$plotthis<- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(fake.data,aes(x=date, y=vehicle)) +
      geom_point()
  })
  
  output$rawdata<- renderTable({  
    nearPoints(fake.data,input$clickthis, threshold = 10)   
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The only part that isn’t working is the renderTable is printing the underlying data for the date object. Dates are stored as integers, they only appear formatted as dates because an appropriate print methods takes that integer and converts it. Your data *is* a date, you just need to figure out why shiny is converting it back to the underlying integer when printing the table.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the date format as in `as.Date(fake.data$date, "%m/%d/%y")`

Comment: Just reviewing the docs it might be that renderTable is only for true table objects, which means you might end up losing some of the formatting. Maybe renderDataTable, which I think is specifically for data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
library(lubridate)
fake.data$new_date <- dmy(fake.data$date)
```